# How to import the JFXtras libraries to use in an assignment project?

Tags: javafx, import, javafx-2, javafx-8, jfxtras

What's the best way of importing the JFXtras libraries (specifically, jfxtras-labs) so that I can use them in my assignment project? I need to make sure that my code is able to run on both my and my professor's computer.

I'm new to JFXtras so any guidance would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with JFXtras, but is a standard Java question: you download the appropriate jars (which is jfxtras-labs-[version].jar), plus any dependent jars (like jfxtras-common-[version].jar), and include them in Java's classpath. Build systems like Maven or Gradle make including dependencies easier, by doing the downloading and including for you.